# Forget login from connection drop down menu

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, logins, connections

Recently I logged myself as a different user (testUser) but now that user seems to be persisted in the drop-down menu of connection dialogue box and I couldn't find a way of getting rid of it. Even worse, it seems to be the default login as whenever I change my connection I have to go to the drop-down menu and choose my usual user otherwise the connection will be made in testUser's context.
How can I get rid of testUser from connection dialogue box?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SSMS 2008, I believe you need to delete the file `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\%Version%\SqlStudio.bin`

This will, however, clear ALL of the logins and saved servers.  You may be able to edit the file using an editor, but I believe it would just be easier to start from scratch.

If you are using SSMS 2012 or greater, you can simply delete the server from the dropdown and that will allow you to start fresh with just that server by highlighting it in the dropdown and hitting `Delete`

See below link for reference to Aaron Bertrand's answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10993861/how-to-remove-cached-server-names-from-the-connect-to-server-dialog